# why colour cannot be applied to faces

Tags: mesh

[image]
I am applying colour to the object.
When doing the brush on the left leg, the colour only appears on any faces at the rear of the leg that are in line of fire of brush.
This has only happened on this model. I edited the mesh using a copy of right leg mirrored. Why is the paint going through the one front face and painting the one behind it?

An image or sample material as the link source on the unwrapped template is mapped as it should be.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I can only assume that what you don't expect is in this line *"left leg faces have the colour appearing, sort of mess, on the opposite leg faces"* but it's not clear how can color be on left leg faces while being on the opposite leg faces, it's like Mobius strip from description. When mirroring note that UV coordinates will be mirrored as well and might overlap original ones which will mean painting as well. Aside from that rephrase and clarify your question.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a screenshot which uses a generated color grid texture instead of the one you're currently using? This will help us see if something went wrong with UV-unwrapping. Also, you should expect odd things after just a few hours of using blender; you can't possibly understand how the software works at this point.